# Button's click event not firing when another button is next to it

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 buttons that are dynamically injected on a page, both buttons have a `click` event listener attached to them.

When a `div` gets injected with `Button A` but not `Button B`, `Button A` works. However, when `Button A` as well as `Button B` get injected side-by-side, only `Button B` works.

**Button A**

HTML

```html
<div id="1" class="classA" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
  <i class="fa fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
</div>
```

JS

```js
document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  functionA()
})
```

**Button B**

HTML

```html
<div id="2" class="classB" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
  <i class="fa fa fa-clock-o"></i>
</div>
```

JS

```js
document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  functionB()
})
```

The way I'm injecting is by looping over elements on the page then using `document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[i].innerHTML += Button` to add the button, Button A is always added first, Button B gets removed after it's clicked but even then Button A's event doesn't fire. Both buttons are added the exact same way, just different loops.

Comment: can you paste your full code instead of snippet, i can't reproduce your bug ?

Comment: perhaps you're doing something wrong when in the code that performs `dynamically injected on a page`

Comment: @JaromandaX I added some more information

Comment: still not enough information to see what you're doing wrong. Sorry

Comment: Are these "buttons" added on the page multiple times or is there only one instance per button?

Comment: Re-assigning content to the `.innerHTML` property of a DOM element (and adding text with `+=` _is_ a re-assigment) will remove all previously added event listeners. You could use the element method `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",<button code>)` instead. This would at lest leave previously added event handlers intact. However, using delegated event handling would be a better approach in situations like this.

Comment: Thank you @CarstenMassmann that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am unable to comment and must post an answer (not enough reputation to do comments).

Could you confirm if after the injection, you can see both button elements? It is not possible to tell from the available code. There *could* be something overlapping Button A and preventing you from interacting with it.

How about console errors? Open up devtools to see if there's anything there.

Inject both buttons, and try to run `document.getElementById("1").onclick()` in the devtools console. What do you get?

Comment: using `onclick()` doesn't work, probably because I'm injecting them using a Chrome Extension. Regardless, I added `console.log()`s and nothing happens when I click Button A in the presence of Button B, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: It should still work even if the element was injected. (I just tested on an extension of mine)

Breaking down the `document.getElementById().onclick()`:
`document.getElementById()` is just JavaScript going through the HTML DOM and finding the first element that has that matching string. `onclick()` tells the code to click, as if it were by a mouse/cursor.


I am missing information, but, it was my fault as well.  
Assuming it was a successful injection and you can see the elements, since you are using a `<div>` element, you cannot expect `onclick()` to work. In this case, do `click()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `div` elements are not made to be used as buttons. There is `button` element for it. In addition it'll have better compatibility with screen readers.

```html
<button id="1" class="classA" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
</button>
```

I'm not sure how your full code looks, but if it actually just calls an another function, there's a way to simplify it:

```js
document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click', functionA)
```

If you are not sure if it works, open console and call this line of code:

```js
document.getElementById('1').click()
```

This will fire all events tied to the click event.